# sed to replace multiple words but skip one

Tags: bash, sed

I am using sed to find and replace words in a file that have matching words with

```
sed -i "s|word|words|g" file
```

I would like it to change the first, skip the second and change the third match

```
file

var1=word
var2=/tmp/word
var3=word.txt

file 

var1=words
var2=/tmp/word
var3=words.txt
```

Is it possible to keep var2 as is?

Comment: It's pretty straightforward with `awk`. Is using `sed` a requirement?

Comment: No, sed is not a requirement. I have just been working with sed and don't know much about awk

Comment: did you don't want to replace the word which was not preceded by `/` ?

Comment: yes, only var1 and var3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -i "s|word|words|;s||words|2" file
```

Change the 1st than the second (that is the 3th originaly due to first replacement)

but this is by line (default for sed)

so it is (for a file)

```
sed -i 'H;${x;s/word/&s/;s//&s/2;s/.//p;}' file
```

that first load the whole file in buffer before making the change

Answer (score 0):

Try with awk:

```
awk <file '/word/{num=num+1}{if (num!=2) gsub("word","words"); print}'
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try and work with it so it replace the words in the file

Answer (score 0):

`sed 'H;$!d;x;:a;s/word/MATCH/1;s/word/IGNORE/1;s/word/MATCH/1;t a;s/MATCH/words/g;s/IGNORE/word/g' file`

Okay, this may seem complicated at first but its simple - this copies all the text into the Hold space, after that it uses a 3 pattern first occurence match to modify the looked for text (word) with a substitute constant (to avoid reprocessing) then loops (t a) back to the label (:a) until the whole file is processed afterward it replaces the substitute constants.

You can use whatever substitute constants (MATCH,IGNORE) you want if those are problem for your data.